# how to selfhost cxf webservice without using any application server

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, self-hosting

I want to selfhost webservice using Apache CXF like in WCF. So, I want to know whether we can host webservices without any application server? If yes, can I have a HelloWorld! sample of that too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use the JAX-WS stack available in the JRE.

The Endpoint class can publish an object with JAX-WS annotations as a web service.